# Undo "New group from selection" project xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I accidentally added my project to a group, and now I can't remove it from it in xcode 4, any ideas? If I drag it out, it asks me to create a workspace...

[image: The problem]

**EDIT: I reported this to apple in the bug reporter, I'll keep you guys updated**

Comment: hahahhahahahhaha >_< sorry, i did the same exact thing (so i'm not laughing AT you, rather, with you), but this is just so funny!! but in all seriousness, thanks for posting this question. It's been a while, has Apple gotten back to you about this bug yet?

Comment: Nope, never heard back !

Comment: Anyone seen this lately? It's been a while for me. But I'm probably working with bare projects a lot less than I used to.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is a project without a workspace?

Close Xcode. Back up the .xcodeproj, then right click the original and **Show Package Contents**. Inisde, you'll see a file called **project.xcworkspace**. This is a workspace created by Xcode when a project is open without a xcworkspace, and it contains this grouping information.

Move this to the trash and reopen the project in Xcode; it will generate a new, default project.xcworkspace without the grouping.

Comment: This fix still works and i just fixed it in xcode 6.4

Answer (score 9):

or you can just manually edit the contents.xcworkspacedata file to do this:

1. close xcode
2. right click on your project's .xcodeproj, then click "Show Package Contents"
3. inside .xcodeproj, right click on project.xcworkspace, then click "Show Package Contents"
4. inside project.xcworkspace, open contents.xcworkspacedata with a text editor. remove the < Group > section from the xml and just leave the < FileRef > section intact like so:

   From :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Workspace
      version = "1.0">
      <Group
         location = "container:"
         name = "New Group">
         <FileRef
            location = "self:ProjectName.xcodeproj">
         </FileRef>
      </Group>
   </Workspace>
   ```

   Into:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Workspace
      version = "1.0">
      <FileRef
         location = "self:ProjectName.xcodeproj">
      </FileRef>
   </Workspace>
   ```
5. save it and re-open your xcode project and it would be back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to drag it out to be a top-level item in the sidebar, but you have to be very careful where you release the mouse while dragging it out -- the horizontal position where you release it determines where it ends up. If that doesn't work, you may want to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: No dice, it always prompt me to create a new workspace, and I'm dragging the file out at the right place, this is probably a bug...